# the formula gives an incorrect result (turning a point by a given angle)

Tags: java

I want to calculate the coordinates of the points of the triangle when rotated by 45 degrees.
I decided to use this formula.but I don't understand where I made a mistake, since I kind of wrote everything correctly.
While for the x coordinates I get the correct results, but the problem is with y.
can you tell me what I was wrong about?thank you in advance.

[image]

```
class Point {
     Double x;
     Double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {

        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
        }

        public double getX() {
        return x;
        }
        public void setX(double x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public void setY(double y) {
            this.y = y;
            }
        public Point() {
            x=0.0;
            y=0.0;
            
        }
        public String toString() {
            
            return x + " " + y + "\n";
        }
    }

class Triangle{
    public Point A;
    public Point B;
    public Point C;
    
    public Triangle (Point _a, Point _b,Point _c) {
        A=_a;
        B=_b;
        C=_c;
        



    public void sd_alfa(double d) {
        Point CG=new Point((A.x+B.x+C.x)/3.0,(A.y+B.y+C.y)/3.0);
        A.x=CG.x+(A.x-CG.x)*Math.cos(d)-(A.y-CG.y)*Math.sin(d);
        A.y=CG.y+(A.x-CG.x)*Math.sin(d)+(A.y-CG.y)*Math.cos(d);
        B.x=CG.x+(B.x-CG.x)*Math.cos(d)-(B.y-CG.y)*Math.sin(d);
        B.y=CG.y+(B.x-CG.x)*Math.sin(d)+(B.y-CG.y)*Math.cos(d);
        C.x=CG.x+(C.x-CG.x)*Math.cos(d)-(C.y-CG.y)*Math.sin(d);
        C.y=CG.y+(C.x-CG.x)*Math.sin(d)+(C.y-CG.y)*Math.cos(d);
    }
    public String Draw() {
        
        return " "+"A "+ A + " "+ "B "+ B + " "+ "C "+ C;
    }
    
}

public class EightLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Point a = new Point(1,1);
        Point b = new Point(3,3);
        Point c = new Point(3,1);
        System.out.println("A = " + a.toString());
        Triangle T = new Triangle(a, b, c);
        System.out.println("Triangle = \n" + T.Draw());
        //T.sd_up(2.0);
      //  System.out.println("Triangle = \n" + T.Draw());
        T.sd_alfa(Math.toRadians(45.0));
        System.out.println("Triangle = \n" + T.Draw());

    }

}
```

My result:

> A 1.8619288125423017 0.8619288125423017
>
> B 1.8619288125423021 2.276142374915397
>
> C 3.276142374915397 1.8619288125423017

The result I want to get:

> 1.8633095244169 0.25578643762691
>
> 1.8633095244169 3.0842135623731
>
> 3.27752308679 1.67

Comment: Seems odd that you update the x coordinate of each point and then you use the updated value to calculate the new y coordinate.

Comment: @khelwood has sharp eyes!

Comment: @khelwood that is, I have to create new objects with calculated new coordinates.

Comment: @khelwood but how do I output them to the console then?

Comment: You create a temporary variable to hold the x value, and then assign it to `A.x` *after* calculating `A.y`. Same for `B.x`, and `C.x`. As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, I'd rather create a temporary variable, it will be easier, thank you.